# Explosions Sprite Despears Way To Fast When Enemy is Killed How Do Fix This?

Tags: python, pygame

on my draw I did this but the explosion doesnt event last a sec and just dispears
is there a better way I could do this instead of saying if the enemy health is greater then this load this?

```
            for enemys in enemying:
                if enemys.health < -4
                    for explode in explodes:
                        explode.draw((enemys.hitbox, enemys.hitbox))
```

my explosion class

```
    class explode:
        
        def __init__(self,x,y,height,width,color):
            self.x = x
            self.y = y
            self.height = height
            self.width = width
            self.explode = [
            pygame.image.load("spark_01.png"),
            pygame.image.load("spark_02.png"),
            pygame.image.load("spark_03.png"),
            pygame.image.load("spark_04.png"),
            pygame.image.load("spark_05.png"),
            pygame.image.load("spark_06.png"),
            pygame.image.load("spark_07.png")]

            self.explode = [pygame.transform.scale(image,(image.get_width()//5,image.get_height()//5)) for image in self.explode]

            self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,height,width)
            self.direction = "blobright"
            self.anim_index = 0
        def draw(self,x):
             
            self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
            if self.direction == "blobright":
                window.blit(self.explode[self.anim_index], self.rect)
                self.anim_index += 1
                if self.anim_index == len(self.explode):
                    self.anim_index = 0
            



    black = (0,0,0)
    explode1 = explode(400,450,50,50,black)
    explodes = [explode1]
```

this is where I delete the enemys

```
            for enemyshoot in enemyshooting:
                for bullet in bullets:
                    if bullet.rect.colliderect(enemyshoot.hitbox):
                        if enemyshoot.health > -8:
                            enemyshoot.health -= 1
                            bullets.pop(bullets.index(bullet))
                        else:
                            del enemyshooting[one]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a great start. If nothing needs to happen while the explosion is going on, you could use a sleep command in your loop. >> time.sleep(0.01)

If the action has to continue on the screen during the explosion, then you will need to use a timer and keep returning to that function after each duration to draw the next frame. Just initialize using >> T0 = time.time() before the explosion, visit the function when time.time()-T0 > 0.01 seconds (for example) and reset T0 = time.time() after each frame is drawn. Return a 'finished' value when the animation is over, so you can remove it from your enemy list.

Comment: could you help me with that?

Comment: Sure. Let me write an example for you this evening after dinner and I'll post it here.  Check back tonight or tomorrow.

Comment: It is pretty rare for you to have an explosion or other event happening in a game where nothing else needs to happen during that animation. A sleep inside of a game is almost always a bad idea since it does block all other game activity, which is almost never a viable option.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the example I promised. Notice how the system clock and a flag
are used to control animation speed so that different actions can happen on the screen at different speeds. This program is written quick-and-dirty. There are MUCH more efficient ways to handle the animation so that the screen is only drawn to when it is time for something to move, and ONLY those parts of the screen that have changed are drawn and refreshed. But don't worry about that. The lesson here is how to use the clock to slow down your animation speed. What's the old saying? Code now, refactor later? Words to live by.

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import * # Pygame Constants such as FULLSCREEN and KEYDOWN.
from pygame import Color
pygame.init()
import time

# ==============================================================
#       Disable Windows Auto-scaling
# The windows auto-scaling feature can mess with pygame graphics.
# Windows-Specific: Delete if you are not on a Windows machine
# If you are on Windows, comment section to see the effect.
import ctypes
awareness = ctypes.c_int()
errorCode = ctypes.windll.shcore.GetProcessDpiAwareness(0, ctypes.byref(awareness))
errorCode = ctypes.windll.shcore.SetProcessDpiAwareness(2) # Awareness levels can be 0, 1 or 2:
# ===============================================================                                                        

# I will base the example on your explode class. If I were writing the
# game, I would use a sprite class along with a sprite group to simplify
# the code. However, these topics are an entirely different branch of study
# so I won't use them in the example. Forgive my quick-and-dirty code.

# I don't have your image files, but it looks as though
# you have an actual animation to use for your explosion that is
# made up of several different frames. We will emulate this for the
# sake of our demonstration.


class EXPLODE:
        
    def create_spark(self):
        TRANSPARENT = (254,255,255) # You can chose your own transparent color. 
        # Lacking the spark files, let's draw our own.
        spark_img = pygame.Surface((31,31))
        spark_img.fill(TRANSPARENT)
        spark_img.set_colorkey(TRANSPARENT)
        spark_rec = spark_img.get_rect()
        
        left_center = (spark_rec.left,spark_rec.centery)
        right_center = (spark_rec.right,spark_rec.centery)
        top_center = (spark_rec.centerx,spark_rec.top)
        bottom_center = (spark_rec.centerx,spark_rec.bottom)
        top_left = spark_rec.topleft
        top_right = spark_rec.topright
        bottom_left = spark_rec.bottomleft
        bottom_right = spark_rec.bottomright
        
        pygame.draw.circle(spark_img,Color("yellow"),spark_rec.center,spark_rec.width//2,0)
        pygame.draw.line(spark_img,Color("indianred"),left_center,right_center,2)
        pygame.draw.line(spark_img,Color("red"),top_center,bottom_center,2)
        pygame.draw.line(spark_img,Color("burlywood3"),top_left,bottom_right,3)
        pygame.draw.line(spark_img,Color("orange"),top_right,bottom_left,3)
        # Now crop line segments that fall outside the spark circle..
        pygame.draw.circle(spark_img,TRANSPARENT,spark_rec.center,spark_rec.width//2+8,8)
        return spark_img
        
    def __init__(self,window,x,y,height,width,color = (255,0,0)):
       
        self.window = window  # Needed so class can draw to the screen.        
        self.T0 = time.time() # Holds the starting time for the timer.
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.height = height
        self.width = width
        
        self.anim_index = 0
        image = self.create_spark()
        
        
        # Standing in for actual animation pages, we scale up the spark image.
        self.explode = [
        image,
        pygame.transform.scale(image,(image.get_width()*2,image.get_height()*2)),
        pygame.transform.scale(image,(image.get_width()*4,image.get_height()*4)),
        pygame.transform.scale(image,(image.get_width()*6,image.get_height()*6)),
        pygame.transform.scale(image,(image.get_width()*8,image.get_height()*8))]       
        
        ''' 
        # Or you can load your spark frames as before.
        self.explode = [
        pygame.image.load("spark_01.png"),
        pygame.image.load("spark_02.png"),
        pygame.image.load("spark_03.png"),
        pygame.image.load("spark_04.png"),
        pygame.image.load("spark_05.png"),
        pygame.image.load("spark_06.png"),
        pygame.image.load("spark_07.png")]
        # All of the loaded images are scaled down to 1/5 their size.
        self.explode = [pygame.transform.scale(image,(image.get_width()//5,image.get_height()//5)) for image in self.explode]
        '''
        self.rect = image.get_rect()
        self.direction = "blobright"     # <-- I don't know what this is, so I've ignored it.
        self.anim_index = 0

    def draw(self,enemy_rec,anin_speed): # Create an animation method to handle the draw routine.

        clock = time.time()  
        elapsed_time = clock - self.T0

        finish_flg = False
        if elapsed_time > anin_speed:  # Animation Speed Controlled Here!!
            self.anim_index +=1
            self.T0 = time.time()      # Reset the start time.
            if self.anim_index == len(self.explode)-1:
                finish_flg = True

        frame = self.explode[self.anim_index]
        rec = frame.get_rect()
        rec.center = enemy_rec.center
        self.window.blit(frame,rec)
        return finish_flg # The finish flag lets the main program know it can delete the enemy.

# ==================  MAIN() ===================
# ----------------------------------------------
def main(): # By using a 'main()' function, your code will run faster!
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((3000,2000),pygame.FULLSCREEN,32)
    screen_rec = screen.get_rect()
    screen.fill(Color("steelblue1"))

    # Declare and initialie an instance of the EXPLODE class.
    # Only one enemy can blow up at the same time for any give instance
    # of the class, so you may want each ship to have its own instance
    # if there is a chance of simultanious explosions.
    # I wouldn't normally use this aproach, but I wanted to stay
    # as close as possible to your existing code.
    explode = EXPLODE(screen,screen_rec.centerx,screen_rec.centery,30,20,Color('blue'))    

    # Let's create some "enemy" units.
    # You would use an enemy class for this (and for drawing them)
    # but this example is qick and dirty, so.. Two enemies coming up!
    
    # One enemy to blow up when it hits the wall.
    enemy1_img = pygame.Surface((30,30))
    enemy1_rec = enemy1_img.get_rect()
    enemy1_img.fill(Color("Green"))
    pygame.draw.rect(enemy1_img,Color("Red"),enemy1_rec,5) 

    # And one 'enemy' to move while the other is blowing up.
    enemy2_img = enemy1_img.copy()
    enemy2_rec = enemy2_img.get_rect()
      
    # Give enemies screen positions.
    enemy1_rec.center = (screen_rec.centerx-300, screen_rec.centery-300)
    enemy2_rec.center = (screen_rec.centerx-800,screen_rec.centery-300)

    # Create a wall for a ship to crash into.
    wall_img = pygame.Surface((100,60))
    wall_img.fill(Color("Indianred"))
    wall_rec = wall_img.get_rect()
    wall_rec.center = screen_rec.center
    wall_rec = wall_rec.move((400,0))

    # Oh, this list is ugly. Forgive me! Used instead of a list of Enemy-Class objects.
    enemy_list = [[10,enemy1_img,enemy1_rec,(2,1)],[10,enemy2_img,enemy2_rec,(3,0)]] # [Life, Image, Rectangle, Speed]


    # Ok, the setup is finished. Time for some action!
    # ===============  BODY  ===================
    # ------------------------------------------
    anin_speed = 0.3            # You can control explosion speed here!
    pygame.mouse.set_visible(False)
    
    run_cycle = True
    while run_cycle == True:
        
        # There are much better ways to erase images, but this will do for now.        
        screen.fill(Color("steelblue1")) # Erase old sprites.
        screen.blit(wall_img,wall_rec)   # Put the wall back in place.

        # Because it is bad idea to modify an object being looped through,
        # we will construct a new list, called 'hold', and copy it back at the end.
        hold = []
        for enmy in enemy_list:
            life,enemy_img,enemy_rec,speed = enmy 
            
            if life > 4:
                screen.blit(enemy_img,enemy_rec) # If enemy is healthy, put it on the screen.
                enemy_rec = enemy_rec.move(speed)
                if enemy_rec.colliderect(wall_rec) == True:
                    life = 0
                if enemy_rec.left > screen_rec.right+10:  # End the program after top ship leaves the screen.
                    run_cycle = False
                hold.append([life,enemy_img,enemy_rec,speed])
                
            else:  # Otherwise draw the explosion.
                finish_flg = explode.draw(enemy_rec,anin_speed)
                if finish_flg == False:           # If TRUE the enemy is ommitted from the hold list!
                    hold.append(enmy)
                    
        enemy_list = hold.copy() # And now the possibly modified list is copied back to the enemy_list.
        pygame.display.flip()
# ================
#   Main
# ----------------
main()  # Hint! For technical reasons related to the compiler being able
        # to control scope and predict variable sizes, keeping your
        # main body encapsulated in a function like this will improve
        # efficiency and run speeds.
```

Answer (score 1):

In the `__init__()` for `explode` note the time when it is called and save it.

In the `explode`s `draw()` only increment `self.anim_index` when enough time has passed since the last time it was incremented (based on the time value you saved in the `__init__()`). This will let you go more slowly through the frames of the exploding animation.

There is really no difference between this and any other object animation, other than once the cycle completes the object (the explosion) goes a way.